# jQuery $.post not working but $.ajax post is working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've encountered a problem while coding some jQuery post requests...
**I generally use $.post method from jQuery** to achieve my requests.

**But** this time **javascript seems not to go into the "success" function of the $.post method**.

What is strange is that **when I use $.ajax (with type: "POST"), it does in fact work**. Strange because $.post is a shorthand of $.ajax.. (See the code below)

For information, the php method called is just a "hello world" and there is no error inside php error log.

Code:

---

```
function setSwitchEnable(switchEnable)
{
    $.post("manager.php", { REQUEST: "SETSWITCH0ENABLE", ENABLE: switchEnable }, function()
    {
        console.log("It's not going there");
    }, "JSON");

    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "manager.php",
        data:    {
            "REQUEST":"SETSWITCH0ENABLE",
            "ENABLE":switchEnable
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("But it does go here");
        }
    });
}
```

This method gives the following output when called:
[Output of the executed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6ApO.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the server actually return JSON? If not, then that's why the `$.post()` doesn't work.

Comment: have u tried commenting the $.ajax part? what happens then?

Comment: @Pointy You're totally right, it was the problem, I removed that last setting "JSON" and it worked perfectly! can you answer the post so I can give you credits? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$.post()` call, you're passing a fourth argument, `"JSON"`, which forces jQuery to interpret the server response as JSON. The `$.ajax()` version doesn't do that.

If the server does not respond with valid JSON, the `$.post()` will suffer an error and the callback function won't be invoked.

Comment: Thanks again, have a nice day ! :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. my php returns JSON via: 
$response = json_encode($output);
die($response); 
Which is: {"status":1,"field":"send","message":"my response text"}

but I still can't enter the $.post() func. it just does not get invoked.  
Any ides?

Comment: @pendingfox well it's hard to say for sure, but please feel free to put together your own question with samples of your own code to illustrate the problem!

Comment: @Pointy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265044/jquery-post-runs-but-does-not-respond-back